# Enlist active submitted 0 instead of 1 and 1 instead of 0 but still giving their correct Flash Success

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

When I get Successfully UNENLISTED(1)! the database saves the digit as 1 and when i get the response Successfully ENLISTED(1)! database saves the digit as 0. I'm very lost and confused from my problem. Is there something special I'm not understanding with CakePHP?

```
public function enlist($user_id_main, $user_id_from) {
    $this->render(false);
    $this->loadModel('Enlist');
    $enlist = $this->Enlist->getEnlist($user_id_main, $user_id_from);
    if (!empty($enlist)){

        dump($enlist);
        dump($this->Enlist->isActiveSub($user_id_main, $user_id_from));

        if ($enlist['active']) {

            $enlist -> active = 0;

            if($this->Enlist->save($enlist)) {
                dump($enlist);
            $this->Flash->success(__('Successfully UNENLISTED(1)!'));
            }
        } else {

            $enlist -> active = 1;

            if($this->Enlist->save($enlist)) {
                dump($enlist);
            $this->Flash->success(__('Successfully ENLISTED(1)!'));
            }
        }

    } else {
        $en = $this->Enlist->newEntity(['validate'=>'validationForEnlist']);
        $en['user_id_main'] = $user_id_main;
        $en['user_id_for'] = $user_id_from;
        $en['permited'] = 1;
        $en['active'] = 1;
       if ($this->Enlist->save($en)){
                $this->Flash->success(__('Successfully ENLISTED!'));
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: When you `dump($enlist)`, is it an array or an entity?

Comment: It dumps an single entity in array form

Comment: Like, it says `Array (...)`? If so, then what you have there is not an entity, and the `->` notation won't work.

Answer (score 0):

I would unset the active index on $enlist right after the conditional:

```
if ($enlist['active']) {
    unset($enlist['active']);
    $enlist -> active = 0;
    ...

} else {
    unset($enlist['active']);
    $enlist -> active = 1;
    ...
}
```

I'm guessing Cake is confused because you have both `$enlist['active']` and `$enlist->active`. If that doesn't work, you could try setting active as an array, like

```
$enlist['active'] = 0;
```

instead of

```
$enlist -> active = 0;
```